# How to raise the NotFound exception with DRF via the urls.py

Tags: python, django, django-urls

Can anyone confirm how you can raise the NotFound exception with DRF via the urls.py ?

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^blog/$', views.page),
    url(r'^$, <?????>),
]
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should raise it in the view

*urls.py:*

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^blog/$', views.page),
    url(r'^$', views.not_found),
]
```

*views.py:*

```
from rest_framework.exceptions import NotFound
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view

@api_view()
def not_found(request):
    raise NotFound('Not Found!')
```